# $ not defined even if script is after Webpack bundle

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have configured Django to work with Webpack on the frontend. The basic layout each page of my app extends is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {% load static %}
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Invoice App</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <script src="{% static 'dist/app.bundle.js' %}"></script>
    {% block scripts %}    
    {% endblock  %}
</body>
</html>
```

My Webpack entry file index.js file looks like this:

```
import $ from "jquery"

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('hello')
});
```

Then, in one of my django templates i fill the scripts block with a jquery function, but it says $ is not defined even though it's located after the webpack bundle and, therefore, after Jquery has been already imported:

```
{% extends "../index.html" %}


{% block content %}
<p>Hi this is a template <p>
{% endblock %}

{% block scripts %}
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        console.log('Hello Template')
    });
</script>
{% endblock  %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
I had to make $ as a global variable and I added this rule to my `webpack.config.js`:

```
{
  test: require.resolve("jquery"),
  use: [
    {
      loader: "expose-loader",
      options: "jQuery"
    },
    {
      loader: "expose-loader",
      options: "$"
    }
  ]
}
```